# Conditional Format based on values in table

Tags: google-sheets

How do I conditionally format each individual cell in `B27:AM46` based on the table in `A94:B114`?

[B27:AM46](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycuE9.jpg)

[a94:B114](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA183.jpg)

Copy of Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oEOcDbQW-QRhjHDY1D04R9XNStyeTKA44GEaPrlh3sk/edit

For example, ARS is 3. Every cell that contains ARS in `B27:AM46` would be red.

- 1 would be grey
- 2 would be white
- 3 would be red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 01

1 - Click Format and then Conditional Formatting. 
2 - Under the "Format cells if" drop-down menu, click Custom formula is.
3 - Add new rule and then Custom formula is.
Click Value or formula and add the formula and rules. for each formula in the following table in step 02

[image]

### Step 02

Paste this formula for each rule

| Rules | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| Red | `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"(.+) "),$K$2:$L,2,0),"")=1` |
| white | `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"(.+) "),$K$2:$L,2,0),"")=2` |
| red | `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"(.+) "),$K$2:$L,2,0),"")=3` |

### Notes

The lookup table needs to be on the same sheet.

Comment: Thanks! After some trial and error I got it to work for my sheet based off your example.